# traducir pagination vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy haciendo la traduccion de la paginacion en un v-data-table de vuetify.
Los textos tipicos de la paginacion tales como:
Siguiendo esta guia de la [documentacion](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#vue-i18n), pero no tengo exito en el resultado.

así es como se muestra actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código de mi vuetify.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "mdi",
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: colors.green.base,
        secondary: colors.teal.darken4,
      },
    },
  },
  lang: {
    t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params),
  },
});

const messages = {
  en: {
    $vuetify: {
      dataIterator: {
        rowsPerPageText: "Items per page:",
        pageText: "{0}-{1} of {2}",
      },
    },
  },
  es: {
    $vuetify: {
      dataIterator: {
        rowsPerPageText: "Elementos por página:",
        pageText: "{0}-{1} de {2}",
      },
    },
  },
};
// Create VueI18n instance with options
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: "es", // set locale
  messages, // set locale messages
});
```

Estoy utilizando:
"vuetify": "^2.5.6",
"vue": "^2.6.14",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo resolví de la siguiente manera:
Agregué este codigo a las propiedades del v-data-table.

```
:footer-props="{
        'show-current-page': true,
        'items-per-page-options': [5, 10, 15],
        itemsPerPageText: this.$t('Rows Count'),
        pageText: this.$t('{0}-{1} of {2}'),
      }"
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]